# Programmatically select a row in Grid in Vaadin 7?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

In the [Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) widget in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com) 7.5.3, we can determine the current selection of rows by calling [`SelectionEvent::getSelected`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/SelectionEvent.html#getSelected()) or [`Grid::getSelectedRows`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#getSelectedRows()).

So how do we *set* the selection programmatically?

Comment: Have you checked if setSelectedRows() is available as stated here in the book? https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.grid.html

Comment: @muenzpraeger Nope, no "setSelectedRows" in the [Grid class doc](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html). Neither does it appear in my NetBeans auto-complete. Thanks for citing that mention in The Book Of Vaadin. I filed a bug report, Ticket # [18,580](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/18580).

Answer (score 7):

While that's true that official documentation for [Grid class](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html) doesn't have this method stated, still you can do it programmatically. I won't argue whether it's a bug or not.  Firstly you need to know what is your `SelectionMode`. Then you can select a row (or rows):

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    Customer c = new Customer(1);
    container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Customer.class, Arrays.asList(c, new Customer(2)));
    grid = new Grid(container);
    grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    SingleSelectionModel m  = (SingleSelectionModel) grid.getSelectionModel();
    m.select(c);
    layout.addComponents(grid);
    setContent(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In newer Vaadin (in my case 7.5.6) there is `select(Object)` method directly in `Grid` [interface](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#select(java.lang.Object)).

Example:

```
Grid grid = new Grid(container);
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE);
grid.select(row);
```

The `row` object for example could be taken from `SelectionListener` event or from added before object (as in @kukis answer).

Answer (score 0):

## Setter Method Missing (bug?)

The Book of Vaadin mentions the setter method `Grid::setSelectedRows` along with a getter.

> The currently selected rows can be set with setSelectedRows() by a collection of item IDs, and read with getSelectedRows().

However, the `Grid` class doc does not list that method. Nor does NetBeans 8.0.2 suggest that method in its auto-complete.

So apparently a bug. See Ticket # [18,580](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/18580).