# Programmatically focus row in grid

Tags: css, grid, vaadin, vaadin-grid

When I start a page with grid, first row is focused and this style is beeing applied(row is highlighted):

```
.v-grid-row-focused > .v-grid-cell {
  // ...
}
```

But when I programmtically change data source

```
grid.setContainerDataSource(...)
```

It doesn't highligh first row.

I've tried to select and deselect first item but it doesn't work.

myGrid.focus() also doesn't work.

How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: We are going to need some HTML to help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900677/programmatically-select-a-row-in-grid-in-vaadin-7

Comment: @Morfic I don't want to select row. I want to focus on it(like a button click). I've tried to select and deselect first row in grid but still it is not beeing focused